# Object with field "type" as type in Vue2 component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to pass an object with this structure into my component (this is an excerpt of the properties the object has; I added the `title` property for clarification as to which are my properties and which is the `type` property on the `props` options object):

```js
{
  title: "myTitle",
  type: "myType"
}
```

When defining the prop inside my component as follows, the Vue runtime warns with `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "myProp". Expected String, got Object`:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    myProp: {
      title: String,
      type: String
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to pass the type definition as property `type` inside an options object as follows, but Vue warns me that `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop type: "[object Object]" is not a constructor`:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    myProp: {
      type: {
        title: String,
        type: String
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I pass this prop structure into my component without being yelled at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if fields exist on an object and check their respective type via. validators for props like explained here in the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation

Answer (score 0):

You can only check if the prop passed is an Object but you can't check what's inside the object as type check.
You syntax is wrong that's why there is the error.

Example below 
Inside Parent Component

```
<child-component
  placeholder="Enter  name"
  label="Name"
  :object-passed="{
     title: 'myTitle',
     type: 'myType'
  }"
/>
```

Inside Child Component

```
     props: {
            label: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: ''
            },
            placeholder: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: ''
            },
            objectPassed: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
        }
```